# set data to CKEditor from server in rect js after load data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

in my code want edit article item:

```
const [contentEditor, setContentEditor] = useState(null);


useEffect(() => {
        async function getLoadData(){
            setitem("");
            setContentEditor("");
        
            try{
                
                const data = await GetDataApi('/article/item?id='+ id);
                setIsLoading(false);

                if(data.status === 1){
                    setitem(data.content);
                    setContentEditor(data.content.text);
                }
                else{
                }
                
            }
            catch(e){
                return(
                    <div>error</div>
                )
            }
        }
        getLoadData();
    },[]);
```

in html

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    data={**contentEditor**}
    onReady={editor=>{}}                                
    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
         const data = editor.getData();
         setContentEditor(data);
    } }
 />
```

**but not work and had error:**
A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I realized**

CKEditor in react can't load data from server in onload component

I solved this way:

> {
> **contentEditor&&**
> <CKEditor
> editor={ ClassicEditor }
> data={contentEditor}
> onReady={editor=>{}}
> onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
> const data = editor.getData();
> setContentEditor(data);
> }}  />
> }